# AutoMLSearch with EvalML returning an error

Tags: automl, evalml

I am getting following error message while trying to run AutoMLSearch with EvalML.
"All pipelines in the current AutoML batch produced a score of np.nan on the primary objective <evalml.objectives.standard_metrics.LogLossBinary object at 0x7f74defbe790>."

I tried the following solution to rectify this, still no use.
https://github.com/alteryx/evalml/issues/3154
Any suggestions?

Comment: Hey Rini, what version of EvalML are you using?

That error typically means there was something wrong with the target. Does your target contain any missing values? Since you're using a binary classification metric, your target should contain only two unique values -- for best results, convert it to use [0, 1], or [False, True].

If that doesn't work, are you able to share your data?

Comment: Hi @Sharshofski, thanks for your reply. Here is the link to my kaggle notebook.  [Heart Attack Risk Prediction using EVALML ](https://www.kaggle.com/code/rinichristy/heart-attack-risk-prediction-using-evalml?scriptVersionId=112794956). Target has no null values and it is already in [0,1] format as well.